# 3 levels validation - dependent drop down list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I already have the script AB and it still working well for data validation from sheet B to sheet A. However, when I want to copy the script AB and convert it to CB for data validation from sheet B to sheet C then the 2nd script not working anymore. Even though, I had changed some var by adding a number or a suffix in the 2nd script. If not, the script AB would not also work. But the 2nd script not running, and nothing happened. Here is my script below, please help me to find out the problems. Thanks so much!

```
`var mainWsVal = "EntryForm";
var optionsWsVal = "Shipping data";
var firstLevelCell = "B7";
var secondLevelCell = "E7";
var thirdLevelCell = "B9";

var ws1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsVal);
var wsOptions1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsVal);
var options1 = wsOptions1.getRange(2, 2,wsOptions1.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();


function onEdit1(e){
  var activeCell1 = e.range;        //TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
  var val1 = activeCell1.getValue();
  var r1 = activeCell1.getRow();
  var c1 = activeCell1.getColumn();
  var wsVal = activeCell1.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsVal === mainWsVal && c1 === firstLevelCell && r1 > 1){
    applyFirstLevelValidation1(val1,r1);
  } else if(wsVal === mainWsVal && c1 === secondLevelCell && r1 > 1){
    applySecondLevelValidation1(val1,r1);

    console.log(onEdit1)
  }
} //end onEdit1

    function applyFirstLevelValidation1(val1,r1){

    if(val1 === ""){
      ws1.getRange(r1, secondLevelCell).clearContent();
      ws1.getRange(r1, secondLevelCell).clearDataValidations();
      ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearContent();
      ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearDataValidations();
} else {
      ws1.getRange(r1, secondLevelCell).clearContent();
      ws1.getRange(r1, secondLevelCell).clearDataValidations();
      ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearContent();
      ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearDataValidations();
        var filteredOptions1 = options1.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val1 });
        var listToApply1 = filteredOptions1.map(function(o){ return o[1] })
        var cell1 = ws1.getRange(r1, secondLevelCell)
    applyValidationToCell1(listToApply1,cell1);
  }
}

 function applySecondLevelValidation1(val1, r1, ){

    if(val1 === ""){
  ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearContent();
  ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearDataValidations();
} else {
  ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue1 = ws1.getRange(r1, firstLevelCell).getValue();
    var filteredOptions1 = options1.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue1 && o[1] === val1 });
    var listToApply1 = filteredOptions1.map(function(o){ return o[2] })
    var cell1 = ws1.getRange(r1, thirdLevelCell)
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell1);
  }
}

function applyValidationToCell1(list1,cell1){
  var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list1)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell1.setDataValidation(rule1);
}
`
```

Please help me to find out the problems and show me how to fix it. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is not too structured. See the [dependentDropDownLists_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160451/269219) script for another approach that may be easier to maintain.